# Adding new line in Trumbowyg editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, trumbowyg

I use Trumbowyg editor (https://github.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg) and I've wanted to override behavior of <kbd>Enter</kbd> (which I've already done).

I've wanted also to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination to add a newline to the editor (like it is binded for plain <kbd>Enter</kbd> by default) but I couldn't find exact method which is used for that in the source code - does anyone know how is it solved?

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to do this - I've added a `keypress` event for `e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 10)` keys with such behaviour:

```
this.editor.trumbowyg('execCmd', {
  cmd: 'insertHTML',
  param: '<p></p>',
  forceCss: false
})
```

I haven't noticed any weird behavior in working of the editor yet, but will report if I find any.

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue closed because this behavior is not possible. Sorry.

Check this: https://github.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg/issues/617

Comment: thanks for the comment! I was aware of that issue but haven't stopped there and tried make it working (and I hopefully managed to solve that problem already - added my own answer) :)

Answer (score 0):

comment out these ↓↓

Ln:1020

```
// t.semanticCode(false, true);
```

Ln:617

```
// t.semanticCode(false, compositionEndIE && keyCode === 13);
```

I could solve " auto `<p>` tag insert ISSUE ".